# What is a 'map' in terms of Ansible variables?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible's documentation, they are using the `map` keyword: http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html

In Ansible's documentation, I cannot find any information about `map`

What is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the example of:

```
# Example setting host facts using complex arguments
- set_fact:
     one_fact: something
     other_fact: "{{ local_var * 2 }}"
     another_fact: "{{ some_registered_var.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.some_fact') | list }}"
```

the `map` is actually a Jinja2 filter and more information can be found per the [Jinja2 official documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.map):

```
map()
    Applies a filter on a sequence of objects or looks up an attribute. 
    This is useful when dealing with lists of objects but you are really 
    only interested in a certain value of it.
```

In fact, in all constructions such as `{{ variable_name | something_here }}`, we're actually saying "pass `variable_name` to the filter named `something_here`" and return the result.

Comment: @user559633 why "list" is required